# React-router messes up request urls

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement the following nested urls with react-router. My problem is that the Feed component sends both GET and POST requests to the wrong url when nested within the Router component, like this:

```
ReactDOM.render((
                <Router history = { browserHistory }>
                  <Route component={ NavBar }>
                    <Route path='/' component={ Feed } url='/api/threads' pollInterval={ 2000 } />
                    <Route path='signup' component={ Signup } />
                  </Route>
                </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('root'));
```

sends requests to `http://localhost:3000/?_=1463499798727` which returns the content of `index.html`, which causes an error since the ajax request is expecting json data, not html, and is wrong anyway.

while

```
ReactDOM.render((
                <Router history = { browserHistory }>
                  <Route component={ NavBar }>

                    <Route path='signup' component={ Signup } />
                  </Route>
                </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('root'));

ReactDOM.render(<Feed url='/api/threads' pollInterval={ 2000 }/>, document.getElementById('feed'))
```

sends requests to the expected url `http:localhost:3001/api/threads` and returns data, and everything works normally.

As a side note, I have port 3000 set for the webpack-hot-load frontend and port 3001 set for the Express backend.

On the Express side, I have the following route set:

```
  router.get('/api/threads', function (req, res, next) {
    Thread.find(function (err, threads) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      res.json(threads)
    })
  })
```

Visiting localhost:3001/api/threads returns the expected data. 
localhost:3001 returns `Cannot GET '/'` which is expected.

Comment: What do you mean by "sends request to the expected URL"?

Comment: @mtaube: In the first example code, the react app continuously tries to GET data from http://localhost:3000/?_=1463499798727 which causes an error. In the second example, the react app GET requests http:localhost:3001/api/threads, which is connected to an API endpoint in express

Comment: Are you saying that you are trying to use ``localhost:3001/api/threads`` as an API endpoint? If so it doesn't belong in your router at all.

Comment: Yes, I am. Strange that passing the url as a prop works when rendering the components normally but not inside a router

Comment: Or are you saying you want to use ``localhost:3001/api/threads`` as both an API endpoint (to return JSON) and a frontend browser URL (to return index.html)?

Comment: I want to use localhost:3001/api/threads as an API endpoint (to return JSON) only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112197/discussion-between-cameron-sima-and-mtaube).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if a URL is intended to be used as an API endpoint and not directly in the browser then it probably does not belong in your react-router at all. **Only put paths in the router that you expect to render a view in the browser**. So if you want `localhost:3001/api/threads` to return JSON via an API call, take it out of your router.

Also, you use should organize your routes using `IndexRoute`. Try this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={CoreLayout}>
    <IndexRoute component={Feed} />

    <Route path="signup" component={Signup} />

    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundView} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Where `CoreLayout` simple renders it's children. I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to display for the root URL (`localhost:3001`) but you would use a component like above.

To use your **API endpoint you can just call it in the component directl**y via it's full path (`localhost:3001/api/threads`).

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately the error persists. I'm 99% sure the error is not on the Express side. I've spent about 2 hours debugging this and I'm pretty certain this is the problem.

Comment: After implementing this router, what happens when you visit ``localhost:3001``? Are you trying to use ``localhost:3001/api/threads`` as an actual URL? Specify exactly which URLs you are expecting to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, hardcoding the url in the component works. However, how are we suppoosed to pass other props into the components?